# With MVC3, is there a way to redirect to an action that will also work with refactoring tools?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The problem is this: You have a ton of controllers and actions and you have to rename one of the actions.  If all of your redirects and links were coded as such:

RedirectToAction("AuthenticationError");

Then refactoring tools would change all the code references, but would not change the above. Worse yet, it would compile and the only way to find all the offending artifacts would be to use find.

I imagine there would be a way to accomplish this via something like:

RedirectToAction(this.AuthenticationError);

That should allow for refactoring tools to correctly do the job - and where it could not the source would fail to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC)

Comment: This looks very promising. Completely removing literal strings would be the ideal case.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper has refactoring support for this if you're a user of that tool.

Just right click on your action and choose Refactor => Rename. This will update any string values in RedirectToAction("SomeAction")

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a checkbox when refactoring that supports "check strings" which might help.